# How to load a pic by beamer

Tags: beamer, diagrams

please say me very  simple how to insert a picture (jpg) that I have on my computer by beamer. I used

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{mypicname.jpg} 
end{document}
```

dose not work. How it  can load my pic?

Comment: What here does not work?

Comment: There is a backslash missing from `\end{document}`, which I assume is just a typo. Also, when posting questions/answers you can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: Your example, if you add missing bacskalsh at `end{document}` work with example image provided by `graphicx` package. Use of `beamer` assume that your document is consist of frames. Try `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{my nice image}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{example-image}%{mypicname}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`, which works as expected.

Comment: How are compiling? Are you using pdflatex or something else like latex? Is the image in the same directory as your tex file? What error messages do you get? [you can simplify your code further by removing `\usepackage{graphicx}`, beamer already provides this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{mypicname.jpg} 
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

and make sure the picture is in the same folder or you would have to set the location.

FYI.......
`beamer` works just like the latex(article) but you have to make each slide or frame per page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Note that here the `figure` environment isn't really needed. (There is no `\caption`, and `\includegraphics` can be placed anywhere, not just inside a `figure`.)

Comment: np  just remember that beamer is like a slide show where each slide needs to be configured properly.